# Code works in php 5 but not php 7, returning single element of array from class function

Tags: php

This was working but now on php7, recent install, returns

"Array ( [host] => 127.0.0.1 [username] => root [password] => [db] => scaryminds ) 127.0.0.1 "

Am after 127.0.0.1 btw.

Relavent code

```
   public static function get($path = null) {
        if($path) {
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $bit) {
                if(isset($config[$bit])) {
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
                print_r($config);
                //return $config;
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling routine line

```
echo Config::get('mysql/host'); // 127.0.0.1
```

MySQL details stored in an array from an include file

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql' => array(
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'db' => 'scaryminds'
    ),
```

So I guess the question is why the line $config = $config[$bit] is returning the entire array with the additional $bit appended rather than just returning $bit.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand what you're asking, your loop is first printing what it finds in the mysql section (which is an array), then in the second iteration what's in the host section of that array (127.0.0.1) . You've commented out the return (which should be after the loop, not inside the loop anyway) so nothing is returned.

Comment: Oops, thanks Joachim, return in wrong position.